# Java files: Suppressing hardcoded text warnings

Tags: java, android, android-studio, annotations

Because of some separators in TextView's (e.g. `...+ "," +...`), I get Hardcoded text warnings. ("Do not concenate text...")

I tried using both SupressLint and SupressWarnings:

```
@SuppressWarnings("HardcodedText")
@SuppressLint("HardcodedText")
```

But it does not work. How can I block these warnings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The name of the lint check you want to suppress is `SetTextI18n`, not `HardcodedText`.

You can also use

```
//noinspection AndroidLintSetTextI18n
```

to target the suppression to the following code line only and not the whole method or class.